# pom.xml tomEE 1.6.0

Tags: maven, apache-tomee

I would like to find/create a pom.xml containing all libraries included in tomEE, using "provided" scope. Goal of this is to make it as "pom parent" of a webproject, and have no risk to use other library version, or other implementation.

Does a such pom.xml exist? or is there a simple way to create it?

thanks in advance

Clément

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to exabrial, the maven dependency i was looking for is this one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: unable to use jettison with this dependency whereas it's provided in lib directory of TomEE

Comment: this dependency is for tomee-webapp : perhaps you have to use an other artifactId like tomee-plus-webapp?

Answer (score 1):

Because JavaEE is a specification, there are several available.

I use this one for several reasons. This is in my organization's parent pom so all the projects automatically pull it in:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0-2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a generic javaee-api dependencies, but a specific tomee 1.6.0, but the dependencies you gave give me the answer, thanks :)